# Send data via Http to a server and show response in a Webview

Tags: android, http, odoo-11

I have an Odoo server that is a WebApp with a website functionality.
I need to implement an Android/iOS app that comunicate with this website functionality.

The website functionality is simple:

1. Take the intervention code.
2. check if the state of the intervention sheet is visible into website.
3. if yes, edit the intervention sheet, if no show error message.

So I want to take the intervention number from Android (for example) and send it by HTTP request and if I get a yes response continue the editing and other stuff in a Webview....if I get "error" show the error into Android Activity.

This is my controller on server that check Code:

```
@http.route(['/checkCodeAction'],
                type='http',
                auth="public",
                methods=['POST', 'GET'],
                csrf=True,
                website=True)
    def worksheet_code_details(self, **post):
        worksheet = request.env['project.task.worksheet']\
            .sudo()\
            .search([('intervention_number',
                     '=',
                     post.get('intervention_number'))])

        if worksheet and worksheet.state_id.is_visible_on_frontend:
            return redirect(f'/worksheetReadValues/{worksheet.id}')

        return request.render(
            "website_project_task_worksheet.worksheet_code",
            {'error_code': True}
        )
```

The request.render load an xml template of Odoo.... I can intercept this call into a webview?
Or I need to implements another controller for Android that receive for example two response (error, url_with_worksheetid)... so if I get error I show a message, if a get an URL I call the webview with this URL.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better to return the error using an HTTP Error Status Code and you would be able to better catch that error status code in your Android or IOS controller.

In Odoo you could return a raw werkzeug response like this (the following example from an existing Android-IOS-Odoo integration done by me):

```
return werkzeug.wrappers.Response(body, status=403, headers=[
    ('Content-Type', 'application/json'), ('Content-Length', len(body))
])
```

or you could add an status argument to your already returned render call that it's already a lazy render response wrapper, like:

```
return request.render(
    "website_project_task_worksheet.worksheet_code",
    {'error_code': True}, status=403
)
```